# Align 4 div in same row with margin 10px

Tags: html, css

I have one parent div and 4 child divs. I would like to provide equal spaces in the 4 child elements with margin right of 10px and margin left of 10px. When we provide margin, the div going to second row, but I want to keep the div in one row with equal width and should use margin.

```css
div {
  width:100%;
}
div div {
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: even without margin or width they will go to the second row since they are block element by default, you need at least to add inline-block or float

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `display: flex;` on the outer div

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

div div {
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Solution without flexbox

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
}

div div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(25% - 20px);
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Nandita,  Without "flex" is it possible to keep in the same row?

Comment: Great :) answer

Comment: thank you, now I know how to align them equally without using flexbox.

Comment: Thanks @Lance2k. Please upvote so that people know its a good answer.